# C# - Try Parse Exact Allowing Bad Dates

Tags: c#, date, datetime, ssis

I'm having a problem with validating dates in C# using the DateTime.TryParseExact method in a script task within a SSIS package I'm building.

What I'm doing is stripping out part of a file name that contains a date using the Split method, and then passing the date portion of the file name into a local string variable named "FileDate". Then I validate that variable value using DateTime.TryParseExact, then if it's good I pass the value to a SSIS package level variable.

For example, if a file is named "filename_11-01-2013.txt" I split on the "_" and retain "11-01-2013" in the FileDate variable. That part I have working and have validated that my variable is being populated correctly.

I've made sure that I have declared "using System.Globalization;" at the top of my script task.

Here's my code:

```
DateTime myDate;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(FileDate, DateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out myDate) == true)
{
    Dts.Variables["FileDate"].Value = FileDate;
    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
else
{
    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
}
```

The problem is it's letting bad dates through. For example it's allowing "55-01-2013" which is obviously a bad date.

It's worth mentioning, just in case this effects a potential answer, that I can control how the files will ultimately be named. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is your `DateFormat`?

Comment: What is the value of `myDate`? If you used it in the assignment, `Dts.Variables["FileDate"].Value = myDate;` does that resolve it? If nothing else, name your files yyyy-mm-dd. They will sort by name in ascending order by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that your format string is `MM-dd-yyyy` and not `mm-dd-yyyy`.

[As per this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx), MM = month, from 01 through 12, mm = the minute, from 00 through 59.

Comment: That was it... Originally my date format string was "mm-dd-yyyy". I feel a little embarrassed but thank you very much!

Comment: Don't worry about it, it's not exactly obvious. Also I would follow the other advice given in this thread and change your filename format to ISO 8601 (yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss) - it's a good habit to get into as it avoids any cultural ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use the exact date format that you are expecting; I am assuming it's "dd-MM-yyyy".
The built-in date formats such as 'd', 'g' etc. are probably not a good fit in your scenario.

```
//const string FileDate = "05-01-2013";       // Success
//const string FileDate = "5-01-2013";       // Fail
//const string FileDate = "05-1-2013";       // Fail
//const string FileDate = "05-01-13";       // Fail
const string FileDate = "05/01/2013";       // Fail
const string DateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy";
DateTime myDate;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(FileDate, DateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out myDate) == true)
{
    result = "success";
}
else
{
    result = "fail";
}
```